# Oil paint with wool

Tags: halacha, shaatnez

Most oil paint is made from [linseed oil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linseed_oil), which comes from flax, the same plant as linen. While this has no bearing on me, I was wondering whether using linseed oil-based paint on wool clothing would constitute a violation of the issur of sha'atnez. Does it do so?

Comment: Why would this be different than using a flax based dye? The issur is one of joining fabrics - using flax thread on wool (or vice versa) or joining flax based fabrics with woolen fabrics through stitching. Coloring isn't discussed in chazal AFAIK, even though it was a contemporary possibility.

Comment: Cloth soaked in linseed oil has a tendency to catch fire spontaneously (http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/12586) so this is a very bad idea anyhow.

Comment: @J.C.Salomon some printing inks I've used have linseed oil in them, as do most oil paints.